# Spring injection is not working if bean created manually in xml

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I have the following beans:

`Bean.java`

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Bean {

    private String arg;

}
```

`Service.java`

```
import lombok.Getter;
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Service {

    @Inject @Getter
    private Bean bean;

    private String arg;

    public Service(String arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
    }
}
```

Here is how I instantiate those things:

`test-context.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   <bean class="com.example.Bean">
          <constructor-arg value="bean param"/>
   </bean>

   <bean class="com.example.Service">
          <constructor-arg value="service param"/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

But when I create the context and look what is inside `Service` instance:

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test-context.xml");
    System.out.println(context.getBean(Bean.class));
    System.out.println(context.getBean(Service.class).getBean());
```

the second `System.out` gives me null.

Why `Bean` instance didn't get injected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your approach to mixing and matching XML config with annotations, it requires `<context:annotation-config/>`. I'd say you'd be safer off doing it one way or the other. If you insist on using XML then inject the dependency in the XML definition

```
<bean id="foo" class="com.example.Bean">
    <constructor-arg value="bean param"/>
</bean>

<bean class="com.example.Service">
    <constructor-arg value="service param"/>
    <property name="bean" ref="foo" />
</bean>
```

Alternatively do it all with annotations

```
@Component
public class Bean {
    private String arg;

    public Bean(@Value("{constructorArg}") final String arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
    }
}

@Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired @Getter
    private Bean bean;

    private String arg;

    public Service(@Value("{constructorArg}") String arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found the reason, I've just forgot `<context:annotation-config/>` in order to make `@Inject` annotation to work.